# SQL Server query XML datatype performance issue

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, sql-server-openxml

I have a XML file stored in a `XML` datatype column `data` in my table `records`.

The table looks like this:

```
create table records 
(
     id int,
     type nvarchar(28),
     data xml,
     posted datetime
)
```

XML data:

```
<Properties>
    <data>
        <Name>novel</Name>
        <Gender>Female</Gender>
        <Age>32</Age>
        <Salary>55k</Salary>
        <Phone>123-123</Phone>
    </data>
</Properties>
```

I am currently using following query to extract data from that XML column which is taking more than minutes in 20K records.

```
select
    id,
    posteddate,
    CONVERT( NVARCHAR(500), data.query('data(Properties/data/Name)') ) AS Name,
    CONVERT( NVARCHAR(500), data.query('data(Properties/data/Gender)') ) AS Gender,
    CONVERT( NVARCHAR(500), data.query('data(Properties/data/Age)') ) AS Age,
    CONVERT( NVARCHAR(500), data.query('data(Properties/data/Salary)') ) AS Salary,
    CONVERT( NVARCHAR(500), data.query('data(Properties/data/Phone)') ) AS Phone
from 
    records
where 
    type = 'personnel_xml'
```

Can anybody help explain how can I optimize this scenario as I need to extract 100 such elements from my XML stored as a column.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have multiple `<data>` within the XML.   Notice I added an expanded XML file which will have two sets.

```
Declare @table table (id int,data xml)
Insert Into @table values (1,'<Properties><data><Name>novel</Name><Gender>Female</Gender><Age>32</Age><Salary>55k</Salary><Phone>123-123</Phone></data>
<data><Name>Another Name</Name><Gender>Male</Gender><Age>45</Age><Salary>75k</Salary><Phone>555-1212</Phone></data>
</Properties>')

;with cte as (
      Select ID
            ,RN   = Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order By (Select Null))
            ,Data = m.query('.') 
      From   @table AS t
      Cross Apply t.Data.nodes('/Properties/data') AS A(m)
 )
Select ID
      ,RN
      ,Name   = Data.value('(data/Name)[1]'  ,'nvarchar(500)')
      ,Gender = Data.value('(data/Gender)[1]','nvarchar(500)')
      ,Age    = Data.value('(data/Age)[1]'   ,'nvarchar(500)')
      ,Salary = Data.value('(data/Salary)[1]','nvarchar(500)')
      ,Phone  = Data.value('(data/Phone)[1]' ,'nvarchar(500)')
 From  cte
```

Returns

```
ID  RN  Name            Gender  Age     Salary  Phone
1   1   novel           Female  32      55k     123-123
1   2   Another Name    Male    45      75k     555-1212
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1570000/john-cappelletti my xml has single data element so in that case i hope i dont need cross apply. So, from the perspective of performance, which one should be choosen, value() or query() ?

Comment: @JohnCappelleti  what is the difference in performance in 'storing the whole xml in #temp table and extracting from #temp' OR 'directly extracting from table.column without using #temp' for my scenario of 200s of elements without repeating <data> attribute

Comment: @LearnByExample Correct, since you have single data element there is no need for the cross apply. and since you know the path value would be faster than query.

Comment: @LearnByExample Regarding your #temp.  Hard to say.  One test is worth a thousand expert opinions  :)

Answer (score 3):

To get a value out of XML in SQL Server you should use the [value() Method (xml Data Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx). And for untyped XML you should specify the `text()` node to get better performance.

```sql
select R.id,
       R.posted,
       R.data.value('(/Properties/data/Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(500)') as Name,
       R.data.value('(/Properties/data/Gender/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') as Gender,
       R.data.value('(/Properties/data/Age/text())[1]', 'int') as Age,
       R.data.value('(/Properties/data/Salary/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') as Salary,
       R.data.value('(/Properties/data/Phone/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(30)') as Phone
from dbo.records as R
where type = N'personnel_xml';
```

Comment: Hi, do you know, if the engine is smart enough to find, that `(/Properties/data/` is the same in all cases? I thought it was faster either to use something like John Cappelletti with `.query()` in a CTE, or - even better - `CROSS APPLY` on `.nodes(N'/Properties/data')` and then use `.value()` on `(Name/text())[1]`. Won't it navigate through the whole `XPath` over and over in this case?

Comment: @Shnugo Hi, I have done some performance testing regarding using `cross apply nodes` to get a shorter expression in the values function and that is slower (not much). Using `query()` is not good at all since the `UDX` operator that creates the new XML is slowing things down. Not sure if this holds true for *all* shapes and forms of XML but it does for all I have tried.

Comment: @Shnugo BTW, the entire XML is available for the value function even if you use `cross apply nodes`. What you have is something called the "context node" which basically is a hierarchical ID that is used as a parameter to the value function. Apparently it is not much faster to find nodes using that instead of a path expression in the internal representation of the XML. At least not so much faster that it compensate for the cost of the extra function call because of the `cross apply nodes`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I had thought, that navigating with a fix starting point (the *context node*) would be faster... This might depend on the depth and complexity... When I've got some extra time, I'll test this out.

Comment: @Shnugo my only focus is on performance. xml is pretty simple but only have huge number of elements (almost 200 elements) separated on 4 heading elements like <data><personnel> 50 <> elements...</personnel><education>50 <> elements</education></data> and the number of table rows is above 100K . Can you recommend some tools that i could use to measure/test the running time.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Do you have any opinion whether to use current node or context node?  The depth of my xml is only 4 levels (at max).

Comment: I tried all the way but still not getting good perfromance. Tried creating xml index on the column but it reduces the performance. Any other thoughts?